# Why is power settings not working in Ubuntu 22.04? Why don't I have performance mode?

Tags: boot, power-management, performance, bios

Recently I switched from Windows to Ubuntu. When I was in Windows performance settings used to work fine. I was able to switch between balanced, power saver and high performance modes, but I noticed in Ubuntu my power modes are not working. Also I don't have the performance mode which is supposed to be the high performance mode.

[image: Screenshot of power settings]

The power saver mode doesn't do anything.

I searched the internet a bit about this problem and found out I can enable the performance mode using the command `powerprofilesctl set performance` and this changes the icon in the dropdown menu.

[image: Screenshot of dropdown menu when performance mode is enabled]

This changes the icon and that is it. I don't see any performance changes. When set in balanced mode `powerprofilesctl` command gives me this.

Balanced:
Driver:     placeholder
Power Saver:
Driver:     placeholder

and somewhere on the internet (I can't remember but it was a page related to Ubuntu) I read that it's a BIOS problem. Ubuntu does not have this feature on some computers (mine is Lenovo ThinkPad L450).

Comment: "*The power saver mode doesn't do anything too*" Your question should show the actual data you used to reach such a conclusion. Summaries lack detail that we need to offer useful advice.

Comment: What processor? `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`; Which CPU frequency scaling driver? `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`; Which CPU frequency scaling governor? `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Comment: I'm not sure why asking these questions. 
AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor
acpi-cpufreq
schedutil

Comment: Have you found a solution ?